# 3-Sasakian manifolds and contact Fano Kähler-Einstein manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, kahler-manifolds, hyperkaehler, kahler-einstein-metric, sasakian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. The **Riemannian cone**
of $M$ is $C(M) = M \times {\Bbb R}^{>0}$ with the metric $t^2 g + dt\otimes dt$.
A manifold is called  **Sasakian** if its cone is Kähler, with the complex structure invariant under the natural homothety map $(m, t) \to (m, \lambda t)$,
Sasaki-Einstein if it is **Calabi-Yau**, and **3-Sasakian** of the cone is hyperkähler. Sasakian manifolds can be obtained from projective orbifolds as follows. Let $X$ be a projective complex orbifold, and $L$ a holomorphic Hermitian line bundle with curvature giving a Kähler form on $X$. Then the total space $S$ of unit vectors in $L$ is Sasakian. It is Sasaki-Einstein whenever  $X$ is Kähler-Einstein, and $L=K_X^*$. If the manifold $S$ obtained this way is 3-Sasakian, this implies that $X$ is holomorphically contact.

Now the question is: is the converse true? Suppose that $X$ is a contact holomorphic Fano manifold with a Kähler-Einstein metric, and $S$ the corresponding Einstein-Sasaki manifold, $S^1$-fibered over $X$. Is $S$ a posteriori 3-Sasakian? Note that the cone $C(S)$ will be Calabi-Yau and holomorphically symplectic, but for it to be 3-Sasakian, we need the holomorphically symplectic form to be parallel, which is not obvious.

Comment: This paper of LeBrun seems to be relevant: LeBrun, Claude
Fano manifolds, contact structures, and quaternionic geometry. 
Internat. J. Math. 6 (1995), no. 3, 419–437, apparently, it answers positively to my question, but LeBrun assumes that X is smooth...